# Ubuntu 19.10 network problem with public IP - connects but cannot send anything (SYN_RECV)

Tags: networking, iptables, netplan, static-ip, telnet

I'm a linux newbie trying to setup a public IP address on ubuntu 19.10.

My netplan file looks like this:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    ens160:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [192.168.1.254/24]
      nameservers:
        addresses: [192.168.1.1]
    ens192:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [85.111.101.244/29]
      gateway4: 85.111.101.241
      nameservers:
        addresses: [62.179.1.62, 62.179.1.63]
```

Routing table:

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         85.111.101.241  0.0.0.0         UG    101    0        0 ens192
85.111.101.240  0.0.0.0         255.255.255.248 U     101    0        0 ens192
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens160
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 ens160
```

From local network on **192.168.1.254** everything works ok. I can visit a website, ssh, telnet from windows to netcat on any port (firewall is down on the machine).
Ping for public address **85.111.101.244** (changed) works ok, but I cannot view website or telnet to any port using this public IP. I mean when I telnet to any port (eg. 80), it looks ok **(screen blankes)**, but **no data gets through**.
I made a few tests using netcat:

1. I ran netcat: `nc -l 2399`
2. I ran `telnet 85.111.101.241 2399` from my windows machine. The **screen blanked** like it was working, but no data went through.
3. `netstat | grep 2399` shows:

   **tcp        0      0 sky:2399                85.111.101.244:57921    SYN_RECV**
4. `tcpdump -i ens192 port 2399` shows this:

```
listening on ens192, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
20:10:41.623769 IP 85.111.101.244.57976 > sky.2399: Flags [S], seq 3016494046, win 64240, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
20:10:41.623834 IP sky.2399 > 85.111.101.244.57976: Flags [S.], seq 253445637, ack 3016494047, win 64240, options [mss 1460], length 0
```

When I do the same thing for the **local address**, everything works fine.
I have no idea why it's stuck on `SYN_RECV` on public IP.
I was worried that it might be something with the network itself. But when I switched this network to my windows server machine, everything worked and I was able to enter the website from the internet.

I would appreciate any sugestions.

Comment: 19.10 is end of life, should upgrade to prevent update problems or edit question if typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a gateway configured on both of your interfaces.  This makes it ambiguous which network interface to use for default traffic.

You should only have a single gateway configured in your netplan yaml.  If for whatever reason you need two default routes, then you need to use routing policies.

Comment: Ok. So sugested fix made it work from the internet :) Thanks a lot. The small problem remains that I cannot access it from my lan on the public internet access. Do you have any idea why that might be?

Comment: Where do the machines on your LAN believe their route is to your public IP?  Are they trying to go via 192.168.1.254?  Is that their configured gateway?  You may need to enable forwarding on the Ubuntu host (net.ipv4.ip_forward=1 in /etc/sysctl.conf).